# How can I add custom events on array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an Array `var arr = [1, 2, 3]`,I want to implement an method to observe the array changes.
It likes

```
arr.on('change', function () {
    // to do something
});
```

It will automatic trigger the 'change' event when I push or delete data from array.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not possible. Events only occur on DOM elements.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306843/javascript-attach-event-listener-to-array-for-push-event.It might be useful for u

Comment: I'm confused now. Is **array** a **DOM ELement**?

Answer (score 0):

That's the first idea that came to my head:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3],
    tmp = [].slice.apply(arr);

setInterval(function() {
    if (arr.join() !== tmp.join()) {
        console.log("Changed");

        tmp = [].slice.apply(arr);
    }
}, 10);
```

Or the prototype version:

```
Array.prototype.change = function(callback) {
    var _this = this,
        tmp = [].slice.apply(_this);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (_this.join() !== tmp.join()) {
            callback();

            tmp = [].slice.apply(_this);
        }
    }, 10);
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.change(function() {
    console.log("Changed!");
});
arr.push(4); // Changed!
```