# Generating event on Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events, custom-events

How can I generate an event when contents of a Javascript array is modified i.e. an event should be generated when push or pop operations are performed over that particular Javascript array. Basically, I want to track the push, pop operations performed over a particular Javascript array.

Edit :- The solutions which are stated in comments, requires to override the push or pop method. I want to perform it without doing overriding it.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of How to watch for array changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that Arrays are Objects so you can define properties.

```
var someArray = []; // a normal array

someArray.push = function() { // this will override the original push method
  // custom code here
  console.log('pushing something..');
  return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments); // original push
};
// now everytime you push something a message will be logged. Change this functionality as you like.
```

**Note**: someArray.push() will now be enumerable. If you want to prevent this you can define a 'push' property using Object.property method.

```
Object.defineProperty(someArray, 'push', {
  enumerable: false, // it's false by default anyway
  value: function() {
    console.log('pushing something..');
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
   }
});
```

Comment: Will try the second method. It seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no native way of doing that. This topic was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306843/javascript-attach-event-listener-to-array-for-push-event) and the suggested solution was to implement a wrapper class for your arrays.

Another way would be to only implement a wrapper `push` function and trigger the event on function call.