# Synching arrays in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am looking for a way to synchronize arrays within an AngularJS controller.

**Example:**

```
var input = [1];
var synchArray = DatabindToModifiedInput() 
// synchArray is something like this:
// [{name:someObject}, {name:inputElement, Id:1}]

input.push(2);
// synchArray should be updated automatically:
// [{name:someObject}, {name:inputElement, Id:1}, {name:inputElement, Id:2}]
```

Obviously i could register `$watch`es and modify `synchArray` when `input` changes but that doesn't feel very angular-like.

**Question:**

I am tempted to write a filter which i can apply to the `input`-array. However this still feels like i am missing some obvious way to bind the data together within a controller/service.

Is there some way to utilize ngRepeat or some databinding-mechanism for this? Or should i maybe approach this in a completely different way?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, what's the end goal? If we understood where you were going with it we may be able to suggest a better approach

Comment: I would like to bind `synchArray` to the view with `ng-repeat`. This data is dependant on arrays which are managed by several different services though and it felt wrong to use several ng-repeats doing basically the same when i could "just" merge the data beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You should likely make an extended array object as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306843/javascript-attach-event-listener-to-array-for-push-event) post by Jacob Relkin.

That way you could do more than just one array or event when something happens.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.myClonedArray = [];
  $scope.myExtendedArray;

  // Extended array type
  function EventedArray(handler) {
    this.stack = [];
    this.mutationHandler = handler || function() {};
    this.setHandler = function(f) {
      this.mutationHandler = f;
    };
    this.callHandler = function(event, obj) {
      if (typeof this.mutationHandler === 'function') {
        this.mutationHandler(event, obj);
      }
    };
    this.push = function(obj) {
      this.stack.push(obj);
      this.callHandler('push', obj);
    };
    this.pop = function() {
      var obj = this.stack.pop();
      this.callHandler('pop', obj);
      return obj;
    };
    this.getArray = function() {
      return this.stack;
    }
  }

  var handler = function(event, item) {
    console.log(event, item);
    if (event === 'push') {
      $scope.myClonedArray.push(item);
    } else if (event === 'pop') {
      $scope.myClonedArray.pop();
    }
  };

  $scope.myExtendedArray = new EventedArray(handler);

  //or 

  // $scope.myExtendedArray = new EventedArray();
  // $scope.myExtendedArray.setHandler(handler);

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.myExtendedArray.push($scope.inputValue);
  };

  $scope.popItem = function() {
    $scope.myExtendedArray.pop();
  };


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" />
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="popItem()">Pop</button>

  <p>Custom Array</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myExtendedArray.stack  track by $index">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p>Cloned Array</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myClonedArray  track by $index">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>


</html>
```